# Cannot schedule job with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Good day to all.

So, you can see my problem in the title of this question. Here are several other details:

- I created test job that simply prints "hello" in the console and it runs great manually
- I'd chosen "Build periodically" option and tried "* * * * *"(every minute) value
- I added logging for "hudson.triggers.Trigger", as it is suggested [here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Job-not-started-at-all-td380903.html)
- I'd already checked other question here, on stackoverflow, and still didn't find anything

And as a result - there was no logs or errors(in both my log and default log) and job didn't run even once. It would be great to know, what I could miss.

---

**UPDATE:**

Strange things had happened... My main job, that was scheduled "@midnight" for this weekend, had just completed both builds in less then half of an hour O_o.

Test job, that should print "hello" to the console every minute had beed run for 8 times every second in 40 minutes after schedule was applied.

---

**One more update:**

Tried to restart jenkins and my main job, scheduled to "10 * * * *" started right in time... Strange, really. But I hope, it will work normally now.

Comment: Can you add the content of the job? and does it work if you run the job manually?

Comment: Yeah. It works fine in case of manual start. The only content is true in "Build periodically", "* * * * *" as value and simple python script with "print("hello")" in it

Comment: Add configuration page screenshot to understand the issue better.